# BigQuery client Java API with user access token

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, google-oauth

A bit of background:

1) I'm trying to access Google Cloud BigQuery data to build a local rolling database for analytics exploration and development.

2) Because of the nested/repeated nature of the data, I would like to store the data in parquet format.

3) Since python - in my outstanding knowledge :)- wants me to store the file to disk before streaming it into parquet pipe, I would like to run this process in Java and its amazing streaming capabilities.

The problem:

I can run queries on the client BigQuery db but client is nervous of giving me service account or client id/secret.

Therefore, I need to copy the existing R process where we can run queries and download data using an interactive access token without neither above credentials.

I managed to replicate the behaviour in python. But since many weeks now it proves to be impossible getting this authorisation and process through the BigQuery Client Java API.

Questions:

a) Can someone help out on building a BigQuery client Java API without service account nor client id/secret? Just with access token requested once through the website? This is possible and running fine in R and Python.

b) More generally, happy to have better ideas/advice on how to build a nested/repeated database from BigQuery data access?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WRT to auth, this page has everything you need. Service account is the way to go. They can monitor your access or revoke it on their side easily at any point in time. We always use service accounts for this type of work. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: (b) : If using TypeScript instead of Java/Python is an option, then have a look at this [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery). I'm the author. The interactive client doesn't have BQ credentials, the backend has. With a bit of programming you can make the client to be non-interactive and add parquet export using [this](https://github.com/ironSource/parquetjs) library.

Comment: Thanks Graham, I agree Service Accounts are the way to go. But we need to go at the customer pace and deliver before we can go further with them...


Thanks also Winwiz1, the projects looks really well structured and clear. I will have a detailed look at it. But I don't know JS and would not like to add another layer of different tool/technology to maintain.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you are using and explain why is failing? In this way you will save time to the people that tries to answer this.